# captcha validation is not working in contact form7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have used a "Really simple captcha" plugin in contact from 7 . but, it's validation is not working in contact form 7 not even other fields.
    if anyone know this, please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Please update your WordPress version to 3.8 and it works. You can see at http://www.waseemabbas.com/contact/

Comment: always post some material from the link and why you gave your conact link?

Comment: @freak I have shown results so user can conclude its work after implementing the solution. Their is not material to the link :)

Answer (score 1):

You must put the captcha field inside the contact form7 with auto generating ID. Then Its working perfectly.